# Changing the values of all the objects in an array using Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects containing a property called 'memory' whose value is in `MB`. I need to convert the array containing the object with 'memory' value in `GB`. How can I do it using `Underscore.js`.

Below is the code:

```
 var parseSize = function(obj){
   if (obj === 0 ){
    return 0;
   } else {
     return  parseFloat(obj/1024).toFixed(2);
   }
 }

   var testData=[
       { name: 'ddd',Vcpu: 2, memory: 4096, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'}, 
       { name: 'eee',Vcpu: 2, memory: 2040, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'},
       { name: 'ddd',Vcpu: 2, memory: 4096, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'}, 
       { name: 'eee',Vcpu: 2, memory: 2040, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'}
   ];

  testData =_.invoke(testData , function(){
              testData['memory'] = parseSize(testData['memory']) + " GB";
            });
  console.log(testData);
```

The above code is not working. PLease let me know where I am going wrong.

Adding the Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/k29zuba2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of what went wrong in your code:

1. You should use `_.each`
2. You should not reassign `testData` with the result
3. You should be accessing `"memory"` property on each item in `testData`, not on `testData` itself

So change your latter part of code to:

```
_.each(testData , function(datum){
    datum['memory'] = parseSize(datum['memory']) + " GB";
});

console.log(testData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This is built into JavaScript since ES5:

```
var result = testData.map(function(x) {
    x.memory = parseSize(x.memory) + ' GB'
    return x
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using underscore [_.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) you can do the following:

```
 _.each(testData , function( item ){
    item['memory'] = parseSize(item['memory']) + " GB";
 });
```

See [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k29zuba2/3/).

Don't use map or forEach if you want support for older browsers like IE8.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parseSize = function(obj){
   if (obj === 0 ){
    return 0;
   } else {
     return  parseFloat(obj/1024).toFixed(2);
   }
 }

   var testData=[
       { name: 'ddd',Vcpu: 2, memory: 4096, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'}, 
       { name: 'eee',Vcpu: 2, memory: 2040, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'},
       { name: 'ddd',Vcpu: 2, memory: 4096, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'}, 
       { name: 'eee',Vcpu: 2, memory: 2040, os: 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)'}
   ];

  testData.forEach(function(d){ d.memory = parseSize(d.memory); });

  console.log(testData);
```